# ElasticSearch aggregation get hit with min date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

How can I get hit with min date after aggregation? 
I have aggregation by some field, then `subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.min("createdDate")` with this date and then `topHits` subAggregation. But it returns me 3 hits, not 1 with this value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `size` attribute of TopHits and set it to one. For more info, please consult https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_options_2